# Rotate ctable, manipulate sideways

Tags: tables, rotating

When using ctable and sideways, the tables are rotated automatically.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ctable}
```

With some of the tables I would like to adjust the angle myself (so it rotates 270 instead of 90 degrees). Any way I can do this?

```
\ctable[caption= Descriptive statistics, label=desc_stat_fut, doinside=\small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}, center, sideways]{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX}{\tnote[]{The sample totals 1728 observations. THIS NOTE IS VERY LONG!}}{
\toprule 
\multicolumn{14}{c}{Descriptive statistics} \\
& Mean. & Med & Min & Max & StDev & Skew & Kurt & $\rho_{1}$ & $\rho_{5}$ & $\rho_{12}$ & JB & Q(10) & PP \\
  \midrule
$P_{t}$ & 58.23 & 56.48 & 25.19 & 145.29 & 25.73 & 1.07 & 0.91 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.97 & 
397.72 & 17285.06 & -1.62 \\
 $\log(P_{t})$ & 3.97 & 4.03 & 3.23 & 4.98 & 0.42 & 0.15 & -0.70 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 
43.09 & 17217.45 & -1.83 \\
  $P_{t}-P_{t-1}$ & 0.02 & 0.02 & -10.52 & 16.37 & 1.55 & 0.42 & 11.83 & -0.03 & -0.02 & 0.07 & 
10368.48 & 16.37 & -43.10 \\
   $\log\left(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}}\right)$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & -0.13 & 0.15 & 0.03 & -0.07 & 3.42 & -0.04 & -0.04 & 0.09 & 862.62 
& 32.05 & -43.68 \\
 $\left(\log(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}})\right)^{2}$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 6.56 & 59.28 & 0.17 & 0.20 & 0.21 & 
271607.31 & 1041.23 & -40.44 \\
\bottomrule
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea: changing the angle just for only some of the tables will render the general layout inconsistent.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Actually I only need to change the angel for one table. (and I really need to change it!!)

Comment: three hours to deadline! HELP!

Comment: ctable relies on rotating and its `sidewaystable` environment. As this package doesn't provide the functionality you need, there's little you can do with `\ctable`.

Answer (score 1):

then do not use `\ctable`. Simply use `\rotatebox{270}{...}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}    
\begin{document}

\rotatebox{270}{\minipage{\linewidth}%
\small
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\resizebox{0.75\textheight}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{14}l @{}}\toprule 
\multicolumn{14}{c}{Descriptive statistics} \\
& Mean. & Med & Min & Max & StDev & Skew & Kurt & $\rho_{1}$ & $\rho_{5}$ & $\rho_{12}$ & JB & Q(10) & PP \\
  \midrule
$P_{t}$ & 58.23 & 56.48 & 25.19 & 145.29 & 25.73 & 1.07 & 0.91 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.97 & 
397.72 & 17285.06 & -1.62 \\
 $\log(P_{t})$ & 3.97 & 4.03 & 3.23 & 4.98 & 0.42 & 0.15 & -0.70 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 
43.09 & 17217.45 & -1.83 \\
  $P_{t}-P_{t-1}$ & 0.02 & 0.02 & -10.52 & 16.37 & 1.55 & 0.42 & 11.83 & -0.03 & -0.02 & 0.07 & 
10368.48 & 16.37 & -43.10 \\
   $\log\left(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}}\right)$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & -0.13 & 0.15 & 0.03 & -0.07 & 3.42 & -0.04 & -0.04 & 0.09 & 862.62 
& 32.05 & -43.68 \\
 $\left(\log(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}})\right)^{2}$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 6.56 & 59.28 & 0.17 & 0.20 & 0.21 & 
271607.31 & 1041.23 & -40.44 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\captionof{table}{Descriptive statistics\label{desc_stat_fut}}
\endminipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, but do not have the time to change all. Any way I can rotate only on of the tables?

Comment: three hours to deadline! HELP!

Comment: @latexmp: ??? It is the same table and the only change is to use a default tabular ...

Comment: Sorry, forgot that i have a \tnote[]{} in the ctable. I will edit.

Comment: @latexmp: you can add the note using a `\multicolumn` after the `\bottomline` command.

Answer (score 0):

*As this is still the top search result regarding this problem, here the solution to it using only the ctable package.*

As stated at the *sideways* option in the [ctable manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/ctable/0) use `\setupctable{captionsleft}` or `\setupctable{captionsright}` before the table and reset it to back to the default with `\setupctable{captionsinside}` afterwards.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[lmargin=25mm,rmargin=25mm,tmargin=27mm,bmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\setupctable{captionsright}% turns the caption of all following sidewaystables to the right
\ctable[
    caption=Descriptive statistics,
    label=desc_stat_fut,
    doinside=\small \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}, 
    center,
    sideways
]{
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
}{
    \tnote[]{The sample totals 1728 observations. THIS NOTE IS VERY LONG!}
}{
    \toprule 
    \multicolumn{14}{c}{Descriptive statistics} \\
        & Mean. & Med   & Min   & Max   & StDev & Skew  & Kurt  & $\rho_{1}$    & $\rho_{5}$    & $\rho_{12}$   & JB    & Q(10) & PP \\
    \midrule
    $P_{t}$ & 58.23 & 56.48 & 25.19 & 145.29 & 25.73 & 1.07 & 0.91 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.97 & 
    397.72  & 17285.06 & -1.62 \\
    $\log(P_{t})$ & 3.97 & 4.03 & 3.23 & 4.98 & 0.42 & 0.15 & -0.70 & 1.00 & 0.98 & 0.97 & 
    43.09 & 17217.45 & -1.83 \\
    $P_{t}-P_{t-1}$ & 0.02 & 0.02 & -10.52 & 16.37 & 1.55 & 0.42 & 11.83 & -0.03 & -0.02 & 0.07 & 
    10368.48 & 16.37 & -43.10 \\
    $\log\left(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}}\right)$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & -0.13 & 0.15 & 0.03 & -0.07 & 3.42 & -0.04 & -0.04 & 0.09 & 862.62 
    & 32.05 & -43.68 \\
    $\left(\log(\frac{P_{t}}{P_{t-1}})\right)^{2}$ & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.02 & 0.00 & 6.56 & 59.28 & 0.17 & 0.20 & 0.21 & 
    271607.31 & 1041.23 & -40.44 \\
    \bottomrule
}
\setupctable{captionsinside}%restores the default sideways behavior

\end{document}
```